# Struggling to get rails 6 API only app to operate the way I want it to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

This is my first rails app, an API only app I am building. Let's say you have a model called "Data" and it looks like this:

```
class Data < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :x, class_name: 'Datum'
  belongs_to :y, class_name: 'Datum'
end
```

And the Datum model looks like this:

```
class Datum < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :data
end
```

And "Datum" has a string attribute called 'value'. Basically when someone hits the "Data" controller to create a new Data, they pass in :x and :y as strings but then the controller intercepts those strings and creates two new Datum with the "value" attribute set to the params[:x] and one with params[:y], and Data.x -> Datum... I've been at it for hours and hours and I can't get the x_id and y_id to set any which way I try.

Comment: Ummm, so the x and y, they actually the same table, maybe you could use STI. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#single-table-inheritance

Comment: I recommend reading the [Active Record Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) docs and consider your desired operation against those supported patterns. Once you have setup your relationships, I would recommend posting a sample of your console input/output while setting these ids with their class methods

Comment: And in class Data, it should be `has_one :x    has_one :y`

Comment: @FeifeiXiong yes I noticed this after I typed it up, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create has_many relationship between Data and datums

Data model

```
class Data < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :datums
end
```

Datum model

```
class Datum < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :data
end
```

inside data controller (create method), you can create @data and 2 datums record as follow

```
def create
  @data = Data.new(data_params)
  @datum_x = @data.datums.create(value: params[:x])
  @datum_y = @data.datums.create(value: params[:y])
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

just provide the foreign_key:

```
class Data < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :x, class_name: 'Datum'
  belongs_to :y, class_name: 'Datum', foreign_key: 'y_id'
end
```